# How to find Desired Count, Remaining Count on ECS service using AWS Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I can find running tasks using the below, but cannot work out how to find out desired count and remaining count if you can help please let me know thanks

```
tasks = client.list_tasks(cluster=cluster, serviceName=serviceName)
running_tasks = len(tasks['taskArns'])
```

Comment: The desired count is not on the task level but on the service level. You need to query the service / all services.

Comment: @luk2302 you might want to post this as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: Thanks Luk in the end I used describe_services https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_services to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
desiredCount = client.describe_services(
    cluster=cluster,
    services = [serviceName]
)['services'][0]['desiredCount']

pendingCount = client.describe_services(
    cluster=cluster,
    services = [serviceName]
)['services'][0]['pendingCount']

runningCount = client.describe_services(
    cluster=cluster,
    services = [serviceName]
)['services'][0]['runningCount']
```

Things like `desired count` etc are characteristics of the ECS service so you have to query based on the `ecs service` endpoints instead of the `ecs task` ones